# Microsoft Translator Text API breaks notranslate spans

Tags: microsoft-translator

I'm using the Microsoft Translator Text API to translate some sentences. My sentences contains some parts of text that I need to not being translated.

To achieve this I using `<span class="notranslate"></span>` by wrapping not translatable text. It works good in most cases, by in some cases MT API breaks this spans.

Examples (Input -> Output):

- `some <span class="notranslate">1</span> text` -> `деякий 1 текст`
- `some <span class="notranslate">1</span> another text` -> `деякий
  <span class="notranslate">1 інший </span> текст`

Good Example:

- `some <span class="notranslate">1</span> text` -> `деякий <span class="notranslate">1</span> текст`

I do not observe any regularities, it happens randomly. Maybe I miss something?

**UPD:**

I tried to send headers `Content-Type: text/xml` or `Content-Type: text/html` - the same result in both: engine breaks some spans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

[Microsoft Translator API 3.0 Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-translate?tabs=curl) recommends to use `<div class="notranslate"></div>` instead of `<span class="notranslate"></span>`.

I use API 2 version, but seems like after changing wrapper to `<div>`, MT API stopped breaking of my *notranslate* wrappers.

Comment: <div> is a block tag and MT engine will break translation if you have some non-translatable text in the middle of a sentence - you will have two parts of your sentence translated separately.

Answer (score 1):

With version 3.0, it's not enough to use `<div>`. Also as Denis Kurochkin warned, it will reduce the effectiveness of the translation (by ending the sentence prematurely).

To achieve this, use `<span class="notranslate">Text won't translate here</span> or <span translate="no">Text</span>`, plus include the `textType=html` query parameter to ensure it is working correctly:

> /translate?api-version=3.0&to=zh&textType=html

Without it (regardless of span/div), it will not translate the text inside the tags, but it will translate the attributes within the tag
i.e. if you have other attributes inside the `<span>` tag then they will be modified, something like this:

> <span data-type=""mention"" class=""mention"" data-id=""39dcf29b-fce0-4a26-90ef-6342e017c1b8"" data-label=""My name has words inside it | Super cool company"" class=""notranslate"">My name has words inside it | Super cool company

Comment: actually, in my case, missing `textType=html` qs in url was the problem

Comment: @BoteaFlorin This is what I mentioned in the answer "plus include the textType=html ...". Can you clarify if there is something I need to adjust in my answer?

Comment: sorry about confusion in my exprimation, your answer helped me, and above response + voteup were a positive feedback

Comment: @BoteaFlorin All good, just wanted to make sure so I can improve the answer if necessary :)