# Prevent the Translator for Microsoft Edge from translating page

Tags: html, internationalization, translation, microsoft-edge

I am serving a html page which is localized from the server side, but if the user has [Microsoft translator](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-microsoft-translator-in-edge-browser-4ad1c6cb-01a4-4227-be9d-a81e127fcb0b) on it will re-translate the language into itself making it unreadable.

I have tried `body class="notranslate"`  and `body translate="no"` and `body class="notranslate" translate="no"`. I have tried adding html `lang` attribute for each specific language but to no effect.

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/prevent-translation) aren't too specific about valid tags. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50128414/microsoft-translator-text-api-breaks-notranslate-spans) may imply that only block and inline tags are valid. Maybe wrapping the whole content in a `div class="notranslate"` will help.

Comment: no, adding it to div does not stop the translator either...

Comment: Can you please inform us whether you are making the test with the MS Edge legacy browser or MS Edge chromium browser? Please also inform the version of the browser. If possible then try to provide a sample code that can help us to test the issue. We will try to check the issue.

Comment: MS edge legacy is being used

Comment: I try to test the issue using the MS Edge legacy browser. I display the text in the Chinese language. I use the class="notranslate" and Microsoft translator is set to always translate the text to the English language. On my side, it works fine and text did not get translated to the English. https://imgur.com/a/ME6HSXE Is it possible for you to share any sample code to reproduce this issue? It will really help us to check for the issue and find any solution or workaround for it. Let us know which exact version you are testing of the MS Edge legacy browser?